# Array of marker objects causes uncaught error in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, object

In php, I create a string that is transferred into a javascript array of objects:

```
<?php
$markers = '';
while($loc = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    $markers .= "{id:'".$loc['id']."', title:'".$loc['city']."', pos: new google.maps.LatLng(".$loc['latitude'].",".$loc['longitude'].")},";
}
?>
```

In the initialize function of the Google Maps api in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    if($markers){
        echo 'var locations     = [' . rtrim($markers, ",") . ']';
        unset($markers);
    }
    ?>  

    //...

    //add old markers
    var markers = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        marker_stack[ locations[i].id ] = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: locations[i].pos,
            title: locations[i].title
        });
    }

    //...

</script>
```

I fill an array with markers, because I may need to delete some of them later. When I do that, I just want to refer to the marker_stack array with the id that I want to delete.

The error message that I get from the above code is in a js file on Google's server:

```
Uncaught Error: Ungültiger Wert für Bauunternehmer-Parameter 0: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] main.js:36
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that your `pos:` property is a string: `new google.maps.LatLng(51,0)` 
and you can't pass a string to a Marker constructor.

The solution is to set `pos_lat` and `pos_lng` as numbers and use those in the constructor:

```
<?php
$markers = '';
while($loc = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    $markers .= "{id:'".$loc['id']."', title:'".$loc['city']."', pos_lat: ".$loc['latitude'].", pos_lng: ".$loc['longitude']."},";
}
?>
```

```
for (var i=0; i < locations.length; i++)
    {
        marker_stack[ locations[i].id ] = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].pos_lat,locations[i].pos_lng),
            title: locations[i].title
        });
    }
```